# jQuery ajax method for POST is failing with "Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy" error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to do a POST call using jQuery $.ajax method at the same time defining the header and the dataType. I tried doing the same in Postman where everything worked fine. So, I copied the below code from Postman's "Generate Code Snippet" tool and tried incorporating it in my method call.

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://link.to.resource/resources/controller/genjpcode",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"    
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{ \"code\":\"manna\"}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

but the call is resulting in following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://link.to.resource/resources/controller/genjpcode' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Below is the code snippet that I am using at the server end to prevent the CORS error in java

```
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
                       ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        /* Enabling CORS filters */
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = containerResponseContext.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    }
```

and this is working fine for the GET calls.

Can anyone here suggest, what am I missing here ?

Comment: We need more code. Either this isn't the Ajax call that's actually fired, or your backend is doing a redirect. (Or maybe something else, but it's all just speculation without more code, both frontend and backend.)

Comment: You can't use POST method when using jsonp. Only GET method can be used. Since the url is not valid that's why you got this error

Comment: @RobinZigmond the backend seems to be working fine, as I have tested it in Postman

Comment: @SaravananN could you please suggest a possible method, where I can do a POST call at same time setting the headers ?

Comment: I copied the jQuery ajax call from the Postman console, and tried to incorporate the same in my code, but I got the following error - 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://resource.link/datafinder/requesting/newcode/genjpcode' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

but it is working fine in Postman